# Basic problem with the definition of exterior point in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem with the definition of exterior point in topological spaces. I am fairly sure the solution of this problem has to be absolutely trivial, but still I don't see how this works.

Here there is a concrete example.
Let assume that $X= \{ a, b, c, d, e \}$ and $G= \{ b, c, d, e \}$. Moreover, let assume that $\tau = \{ \emptyset, X, G \}$.
Thus, $(X, \tau )$ is a topological space, but I don't see how the definition of exterior point captures the fact that $a$ is indeed an exterior point of $G$.

The problem is that the definition states that $a$ is an exterior point if $X \setminus G$ is a neighborhood of $a$. Formally

$$ a \text{ exterior point of }G \Longleftrightarrow \exists V \in \tau: a \in V \subseteq X \setminus G $$

But there is no open set $V \in \tau$ with this characteristics, at least in this example. Does it actually mean that $a$ is *not* an exterior point of $G$?  What am I missing?

I start to think that topology is not the best subject to approach as a self-taught...
Anyway, as always, any feedback is more than welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have not checked the details of your post, but the simple fact that a set $G$ is open and that a point $a$ does not belong to $G$ does not imply that $a$ is exterior. The prototypical example in those things is always the real line, and in the real line one may take $G=(0, 1)$ and $a=1$

Comment: I am not sure I see completely your example. Do you mean that by taking $\Re$ and $G=(0,1)$, $a=1$ is not an exterior point of $G$ if the topological space $(\Re, \tau)$ is s.t. $\tau = \{ \emptyset, \Re, G \}$? If this is the case, basically you are translating my --finite-- example on the real line, and you are also giving me an answer... :)

Comment: Thus, indeed $a$ is not an exterior point by simply being outside an open subset. There has to be an open set in $\tau$ such that the condition I wrote down holds to make it an exterior point. Believe me or not, I did not find this point explicitly in any book I looked around (and they are quite a lot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your finite example $a$ is *not* an exterior point of $G$, as the only open set that contains $a$ is the whole space $X$ (as the only other open sets are $G$ and $\emptyset$, that both do not contain $a$). And $X$ is not disjoint from $G$.

Being outside of a set is *not* the same as being an exterior point in the topological sense. The latter means that the point is "some distance away" from the set, the distance being the open neighbourhood being disjoint from it.

If we have a set $A \subset X$, and $x \in X$ in a space, then one of three things happens: there is some open set that contains $x$ and sits inside $A$, and in that case $x$ is called an interior point of $A$ (and then a fortiori $x \in A$, of course). Or there is an open set that contains $x$ and sits inside $X \setminus A$, and then $x$ is called an exterior point of $A$ (and again this implies $x \in X \setminus A$), and in fact, this exactly means that $x$ is an interior point of $X \setminus A$; or the last option: for *every* open set $O$ that contains $x$, we know that $O$ intersects $A$ and $O$ intersects $X \setminus A$ (which is when neither of the two previous options apply). Then $x$ is called a boundary point of $A$ (and then $x$ can be either in $A$ or $X \setminus A$).

So in your case with $G$, all points of $G$ are interior points of $G$ (as $G$ itself is open) and the remaining point $a$ is a boundary point of $G$ and there are no exterior points of $G$ (which can also be formulated by saying that $G$ is dense in $X$).

Comment: Sir can you explain a bit of exterior point and boundary point ? (Without using the notion of topological space or metric spaces,just on real line) I am taking a basic course in real analysis which introduces metric space later on. So now what I know is "a point x is called exterior point of set $S$ if $\exists$ a nbd $N_{x}$ such that $N_{x} \cap S=\phi$" . My question is if I choose $S$ as any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\neq\phi \forall x$ does it mean that any such $S$ has no exterior point ? (Or I am thinking wrong)

Comment: @MDesmond If $S$ is such that for all $x$, $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon) \neq \emptyset$, then $S$ is dense and the exterior is empty. The exterior of $S$ is really just the complement of the closure of $S$, or (the same set described equivalently) the interior of the complement of $S$.